# Загрузка изображений из интернета в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Пользователь выбирает объект в `ListBox` и нажимает `Button`. Программа должна по названию выбранного объекта найти в Google Картинках изображение и загрузить его в `PictureBox`. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846337/select-and-download-random-image-from-google